# Bash mail doesn't preserve new-line from grep

Tags: bash, email, unix, grep, sh

I am trying to grep something in the script and sending it as an email.The new line in the grep output is not being reflected in the email even if I use double quotes for the variable everywhere. Can someone point out the mistake or provide a workaround? Thanks.

Note: the \n added in the script are reflected but I want the grep output stored in "${Err_state}" separated by a newline.

Code:

```
Err_state=`qstat | grep ${PP_Jname}* | grep 'Eqw' | cut -f3 -d' '`
if [ ! -z "${Err_state}" ]; then
        err_msg="PostProcessing failed for :\n $Err_state \n\n Pls look into logs \n"
        SendEmail "$err_msg"

function SendEmail() {
err_msg="${1}"
err_msg="\n\nERROR: \n"${err_msg}"\n\n Terminating script...\n"; 
`echo -e "ERROR generated AutoProcess.sh:\n "${err_msg}"\n" | /bin/mail -s "OS_AutoProcess_wrapper.sh: ERROR" ${email_address}`
exit 1;
}
```

Comment: The backquotes are entirely unnecessary; you aren't trying to do anything with the output (if any) of `/bin/mail`.

Comment: You aren't quoting `${email}`, whose value isn't clear from the code you show.

Comment: It is just an email address to which the email is sent.

Comment: sed G worked for me as explained in this answer:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3127/how-do-i-add-newlines-between-lines-printed-on-the-command-line